# replace values under condition with mutate function

Tags: r, replace, plyr, dplyr

I´m trying to run a simple `mutate()` function on a dataframe to `replace` values of a column under the condition of other columns.
The problem which since about a week occurs is that the mutate function doesn´t change anything but the first value I´m trying to replace. **There´s no error message**, the code runs as usual but the values of my resulting dataframe doesn´t change.
As I was working with `mutate()` for ages, I really don´t know whats wrong.

Does anyone else has the same issue or knows how to fix this?

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(var1 = rep(c(1:10),2),
                 var2 = rep(c(0,1), 10),
                 var3 = rep(c("2010", "2015", "2020", "2025"),5),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df1 <- df %>% 
        mutate(var1 = replace(var1, var2 == "1" & var3 == "2015", "20"),
               var1 = replace(var1, var2 == "0" & var3 == "2020", "0))
```

Now it doesn´t return `df1` with my wanted values of var1, but only copies `df`, so var1 remains the same.

Thanks!

Comment: 1) `plyr` is retired, you can do most of the thing (everything) with `dplyr` alone. Moreover, loading `plyr` may conflict with certain functions in `dplyr` (like `summarise`/`mutate`). 2) You have a missing `"` in your 2nd `replace` statement. Does correcting that solve the issue?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I only ran `dplyr` and it worked. The problem seems to occur when I load both, `dplyr` and `plyr`. I think I used the `plyr` package for another operation in the same R session, which lead to the misstake. I will come up for this and only use `dplyr` from now on.

Answer (score 0):

Does this yield the output you're after? It wasn't exactly clear from your question and I don't have enough reputation points to comment.

```r
df <- data.frame(var1 = rep(c(1:10),2),
                 var2 = rep(c(0,1), 10),
                 var3 = rep(c("2010", "2015", "2020", "2025"),5),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df1 <- df %>% 
  mutate(var1 = replace(var1, var2 == "1" & var3 == "2015", "20")) %>%
  mutate(var1 = replace(var1, var2 == "0" & var3 == "2020", "0"))

head(df1)

#    var1 var2 var3
# 1    1    0 2010
# 2   20    1 2015
# 3    0    0 2020
# 4    4    1 2025
# 5    5    0 2010
# 6   20    1 2015
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I just solved the problem by the solution above!